# PHP HTML Form and Button Issue

Tags: php, html, button

I have been working on my blogging website but for some reason when trying to call a loginscript from the form below nothing happens. Any suggestions for why would be much appreciated.

```
<form name="sentMessage" method = "post" action = "loginScript.php" >
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your username.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="password" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your password.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-default" >Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If I didn't make it clear when you press the button there is no response.

Comment: Can we have the code of `loginScript.php`?

Comment: your input-tags miss the *name* attribute!

Comment: LoginScrip.php was just an echo to see if it was calling that page correctly, but it doesn't appear to do anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a test, apparently you are missing the name attributes on inputs, 
so you can write something like this :

```
    <form name="sentMessage" method="post" action="loginScript.php" >
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your username.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row control-group">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your password.">
            <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="success"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And your file (loginScript.php must have this test:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo 'OK';
    } else {
        echo 'not ok';
    }
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: Show me your loginScript please :)

Comment: It was just an echo so I changed it to the script Elyass posted while I get it working.

Comment: If it helps, i've been working with a bootstrap theme that I have modified slightly, could something in the css files or elsewhere be causing issues?

Comment: It was an issue with the js file which I have now sorted and your answer works perfectly :D